# Most efficient way to limit a SQL query using count(*) of objects within table?

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    accountNumber,
    z, --long string that contains accountID within
    status, -- red green or blue
    partition_0, 
   
);
INSERT INTO example
Values(123, 'abcde: xyz, accountID: 10434', 'green', 20211010),
(124, 'abcde: xhf, accountID: 25949', 'green', 20211010),--accountNumber 124 would be excluded because it has >= different accountID (25949 and 34322)
(124, 'abcde: xhf, accountID: 34322', 'green', 20211010),
(124, 'abcde: xhf, accountID: 25949', 'red', 20211011),
(154, 'abcde: dasd, accountID: 43341', 'green', 20211010);
```

This table can have 100,000,000->10,000,000,000 rows. Sometimes the system which populates this table does not work appropriately, and I get accountNumbers with multiple accountIDs. They should be 1:1. Those that aren't are artifacts and I would like to filter them out. I have the following set up:

```
with cte as (
select accountNumber, 
upper(substr(z,strpos(z,'accountID')+11,5)) as accountID, partition_0 from example),

cte_limiter_raw as (
select accountNumber, count(distinct accountID) as countAccountID from cte
group by accountNumber), --I chose to put the limiter here because I could call accountID instead of the substr function

cte_limiter as (
select accountNumber from cte_limiter_raw
where countAccountID = 1)

select accountNumber, accountID, partition_0,
sum(case when status like 'Green' then 1 end) as countGreen,
sum(case when status like 'Red' then 1 end) as countRed
from cte
where accountNumber in (select accountNumber from cte_limiter)
group by accountNumber, accountID, partition_0
```

This seems kind of clunky. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I am querying on Amazon Athena.

Comment: You mean that sometimes multiple rows are insrted for the same account id? If not can you please add some example data?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. I have added some clarification to the question via example data regardless, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to do this:

```sql
SELECT accountNumber
FROM example
GROUP BY accountNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UPPER(SUBSTR(z, STRPOS(z, 'accountID') + 11, 5))) > 1
```

i.e. find all `accountNumber` for which there is more than one distinct value of the substring in `z`.

The above is a simpler way of expressing the query, but it's a full table scan. If you have some way of running the query on only new data that could limit the impact.

Your query will do two full table scans since it does `SELECT … FROM cte` twice. Athena will not reuse intermedate results (that's a Presto limitation, it's much harder than it looks for a distributed engine to do that). You could rewrite your query to avoid the correlated subquery, but I think using `HAVING` is easier.

`HAVING` is like `WHERE`, but evaluates in a different phase so you can express properties of a group. Another way of writing the same thing (and which gets the same query plan) is like this:

```sql
WITH counts AS (
  SELECT
    accountNumber,
    COUNT(DISTINCT UPPER(SUBSTR(z, STRPOS(z, 'accountID') + 11, 5))) AS count
  FROM example
  GROUP BY accountNumber
)
SELECT accountNumber
FROM counts
WHERE "count" > 1
```

Comment: A few issues with your answer. I am looking to also select accountID (the result of the substr function). You are only using it in the conditional, but not pulling it as well. Also, I am looking to *exclude* the accounts with 'count' > 1. I would want, then, WHERE count = 1.

Comment: I think you can work a bit on your question to make it clear what you're trying to achieve.